# Call function before return Response::json in Laravel 4 gives "json.parse:unexpected non-whitespace character after json data"

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel-4

My Controller

```
    public function electricityBillAddToCart(){

    $accountNumber = Input::get( 'accountNumber' );
    $amount = Input::get( 'amount' );
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $type = TransactionTypes::ELECTRICITY;

    if(is_numeric($accountNumber)) {



CartHelper::addToCart($userId, $accountNumber, $amount, $type);

        return Response::json("Okay");
    }
    return Response::json("Error");
}
```

The above function is called using the following ajax request

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "/addToCart/electricityBill",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {'accountNumber': reloadto, 'amount': amount},
        success: function (re) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function(re) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
```

The response to the front end would be []"okay", and "Error" would be printed in the console. If the static function that I call before sending the response is commented out it would work fine (it would return "okay", and print "Success"). The code that I comment is

```
CartHelper::addToCart($userId, $accountNumber, $amount, $type);
```

Anyone knows why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There was an echo in the CartHelper class. Once that was deleted, it worked fine